# waiting on background subprocesses in DCL on VMS

Tags: vms, openvms, dcl

I am looking for a way to launch several background processes to run in parallel with DCL. I would want to wait for them all to complete and know whether they all succeeded or at least one failed. This would be like using & and wait in bash.

I read the docs for spawn/nowait but I don't see a way to wait after spawning multiple subprocesses. I suppose I could have the subproceses write to a file when they exit and check the file from the parent in a sleep-loop? But is there a better/built-in way?

Comment: Been a long time since I went near VMS but my first thought was a mailbox. E.g. each spawned task mails success/fail whe it finishes and then your main job just listens for all responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two reliable means are:

If you `submit` them as batch jobs you can use the `synchronize` command to wait on each in turn.

Using `run/detach` to start the processes allows you to specify a `/mailbox` to receive the termination message.

Subprocesses are a little different.  One approach is to share a logical name table and have each subprocess update its status accordingly.  There is no guarantee that an abnormal termination will be reported.

If you are willing to do some extra work you can create a couple of small applications to use either the lock manager or a common event flag cluster to communicate status updates.

Comment: Thanks. synchronize looks very close to what I need. I see that it will exit with the exit status of the submitted job. My issue now is what happens if any of the jobs complete before the program can synchronize on them. I haven't used mailboxes before but I'm looking into your run/detach solution now.

Comment: I don't seem to have permissions to create a mailbox. So I am using submit with the /retain option. I think if I specify a time that is longer than I'd expect it to take for all batch jobs to complete, I should be okay. I'm not sure, however, whether there are significant negative consequences.

Comment: @Jason - If you can `spawn` then you have `TmpMbx` privilege.  Among the vast assortment of things I can't remember is the trick to creating a temporary mailbox in DCL.  It involves spawning a subprocess, checking the process logical names, and using `$GetDvI` to get the unit number of the mailbox.  You can then use the usual DCL commands, e.g. `OPEN`, `READ`, `WRITE` and `CLOSE`, to access the mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

```
$   BKGVFY = F$VERIFY(0)  !******Start of BACKGROUND******
$!*DOC+
$!*
$!* Procedure    : BACKGROUND.COM
$!*
$!*   Abstract   : Invoke Commands in Background
$!*
$!*   Prototype  : @MYDCL:BACKGROUND "RUN PROG1" "@COMFIL" "RUN PROG2"
$!*
$!*   Description: This utility is used to run background spawned jobs. It
$!*                will return control after all of the jobs have run.
$!*
$!*          Note: Requires GRPNAM or SYSNAM Privilege
$!*
$!* Parameters   : P1 = Background Command (Required)
$!*                P2 = Background Command (Optional)
$!*                P3 = Background Command (Optional)
$!*                P4 = Background Command (Optional)
$!*                P5 = Background Command (Optional)
$!*                P6 = Background Command (Optional)
$!*                P7 = Background Command (Optional)
$!*                P8 = Background Command (Optional)
$!*
$!* Change Control Log:
$!*
$!*        Who         Date      Description
$!*  --------------- ----------  -----------
$!*  Scott Kelbell   02/16/2010  Initial version
$!*
$!*DOC-
$   !
$   ! VALIDATION
$   !
$   IF P1 .EQS. "" .OR. P1 .EQS. "HELP" .OR. P1 .EQS. "?" THEN EXIT
$   IF F$PRIVILEGE("GRPNAM")
$   THEN
$     BKGPRIV = "GROUP"
$   ELSE
$     IF F$PRIVILEGE("SYSNAM")
$     THEN
$       BKGPRIV = "SYSTEM"
$     ELSE
$       WRITE SYS$OUTPUT "%BACKGROUND-F-IPRV, insufficient priv (GRPNAM)"
$       EXIT
$     ENDIF
$   ENDIF
$   !
$   ! INITIALIZATION
$   !
$   BKGN     = "BKG" + F$UNIQUE()   ! Background Logical Prefix
$   BKGFIL   = "SYS$LOGIN:" + BKGN  ! Background File Prefix
$   BKGCNT   = 0                    ! Parameter Counter
$   !
$   ! MAINLINE
$   !
$ LOOP:
$   IF BKGCNT .EQ. 8 THEN GOTO LOOP_WAIT
$   BKGCNT = BKGCNT + 1
$   IF P'BKGCNT' .NES. ""                           ! For each parameter
$   THEN
$     BKGLOG = BKGFIL + ".LOG_" + F$STRING(BKGCNT)
$     CREATE/FDL=NL: 'BKGFIL'.TMP_'BKGCNT' ! Create the command procedure
$     OPEN/APPEND 'BKGN' 'BKGFIL'.TMP_'BKGCNT'
$     BKGLNM = BKGN + "_" + F$STRING(BKGCNT)
$     WRITE 'BKGN' "$ SET VERIFY"
$     WRITE 'BKGN' "$ ! Background Job #", P'BKGCNT', " ", F$TIME()
$     WRITE 'BKGN' "$ SET NOON"
$     WRITE 'BKGN' "$ DEFINE/NOLOG/", BKGPRIV, " ", BKGLNM, " RUNNING"
$     WRITE 'BKGN' "$ ", P'BKGCNT'
$     WRITE 'BKGN' "$ DEFINE/NOLOG/", BKGPRIV, " ", BKGLNM, " FINISHED"
$     WRITE 'BKGN' "$ EXIT ! End of Background Job"
$     CLOSE 'BKGN'
$     DEFINE/'BKGPRIV' 'BKGN'_'BKGCNT' INITIALIZED
$     SPAWN/NOWAIT/OUTPUT='BKGLOG'/NOLOG @'BKGFIL'.TMP_'BKGCNT'
$     GOTO LOOP
$   ENDIF
$   BKGCNT = BKGCNT - 1
$   !
$   ! WAIT LOGIC
$   !
$ LOOP_WAIT:
$   CURLOG = BKGN + "_" + F$STRING(BKGCNT)
$   IF F$TRNLNM("''CURLOG'") .NES. "FINISHED"
$   THEN
$     WAIT 00:00:05
$     GOTO LOOP_WAIT
$   ENDIF
$   DEASSIGN/'BKGPRIV' 'BKGN'_'BKGCNT'
$   DELETE/NOLOG/NOCONFIRM 'BKGFIL'.TMP_'BKGCNT';*
$   BKGCNT = BKGCNT - 1
$   IF BKGCNT .GT. 0 THEN GOTO LOOP_WAIT
$   !
$   ! EXIT LOGIC
$   !
$ EXIT:
$   BKGVFY = F$VERIFY(BKGVFY) !******End of BACKGROUND******
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, SYNCHRONIZE is the most robust method.

One sloppy, but often adequate method is to create the shortest lived tasks first with spawn/nowait and spawn/wait the task expected to run last.

To tighten that up you can enter a polling loop with F$CONTEXT  looking of MASTER_PID = your-pid counting the number of returned F$PID values, with optional F$GETJPI

Hackish ways are for example to try re-use a process name, or to try open a process log file not allowing sharing which will only work once the process is gone, or parse SHOW PROC/SUB output.

Maybe you can create a simple shell program to perform a bunch of (lib$)spawns and use the completion AST to figure out when all are done?

You may also want to check out the CRTL function waitpid.

hth,
     Hein.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a piped open in Perl and then wait for it with waitpid:

```
$ perl -e "my $pid = open F, '| wait 00:00:05'; print qq/waiting for $pid\n/; waitpid($pid, 0); close F;"
waiting for 6233
```

Substitute the actual DCL command you want to wait on for the "wait 00:00:05" command.  Here the filehandle F is a write-only filehandle hooked up to the child's stdin/SYS$INPUT.  If the child does any blocking reads on SYS$INPUT, the parent will need to write whatever it is expecting or the child will hang.  Or you can put the pipe character | at the end of the command and then F will be a read-only filehandle connected to the child's stdout/SYS$OUTPUT.  If waiting on more than one child, you may need to use wait() rather than waitpid().

Answer (score 0):

Simply poll the suprocess count.
The "PRCCNT" parameter of f$getjpi is the value you need, the name may be misleading (as total process job count), it is subprocess count.
That is a "oneliner" (of course, a "payd by kB" may split it to half page):

```
$ spawn/nowait command1
$ spawn/nowait command2
...
$waitall: if f$getjpi("","PRCCNT").gt.0 then pipe wait 0::.5 ; goto waitall
...
```

Set the polling interval to sensible value, appropiate for the command execution times, of course, 0.5 sec is not a universal one.